# What are the compatibility risks of replacing METHOD/FIELD/etc. targets with TYPE_USE

Tags: java, java-8, annotations, compatibility

I have a Java package that contains annotations used by external clients. The package appeared before Java 8, so historically these annotations have targets `ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE`. Now the package requires at least Java 8 version. Semantically the annotations in the package are applicable to the types, so e.g. when the method is annotated, the annotation effectively applies to the method return type. Now clients want to annotate generic type arguments as well (e.g. `List<@MyAnnotation String>`). Since we dropped the support of Java 7 and below, it seems quite natural to set the annotation target to `ElementType.TYPE_USE` and, to reduce ambiguity, remove the existing targets.

Here's the question: are there any compatibility risks for existing clients when replacing `ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE` targets with `TYPE_USE`? Is it possible that the existing code will stop compiling? What about binary compatibility? May it cause any runtime problems if the class-files compiled before the change are used together with newer annotations pack at runtime?

Annotations' retention policy is `CLASS` if this matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of source compatibility issues that may arise during this change:

- Methods with `void` return type cannot be annotated anymore. `@MyAnnotation void method() {}` is compilable with `ElementType.METHOD` target but not compilable with `TYPE_USE` target.
- When a qualified type is used in the source code, the `TYPE_USE` annotation must appear after the qualifier. E.g. `void method(@MyAnnotation OuterClass.InnerClass param) {}` is a valid code with `ElementType.PARAMETER` target, but should be updated to `void method(OuterClass.@MyAnnotation InnerClass param) {}` after changing to `TYPE_USE`.
- Annotation applied to arrays will have a different meaning. E.g. before the migration `@MyAnnotation String[] getData();` annotates the method `getData`, so the annotation clients likely assume that annotation is applied to the return type (an array of strings). After the migration, the same code means that the annotation is applied to the array component (string). This might cause a behavioral change, depending on the annotation semantics and how it's processed by clients. To preserve the meaning, clients should update such a code to `String @MyAnnotation [] getData();`.
- Such a change makes all usages of the annotations in Kotlin code invalid. In Kotlin, there's strict syntactical difference between `TYPE_USE` annotations and others. E.g. a `PARAMETER` annotation must be used as `fun(@MyAnnotation param : String) {...}`. This is incorrect for `TYPE_USE` annotation, which must be used as `fun(param : @MyAnnotation String) {...}`. If your clients use Kotlin they will have to fix every single annotation use.
- Such a change disallows using your annotations in Groovy code. Currently, as [Groovy documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-object-orientation.html) says, Groovy does not support the TYPE_PARAMETER and TYPE_USE element types which were introduced in Java 8. If your clients use Groovy they won't be able to use your annotation package anymore.

No problems should arise at runtime though. As annotations' retention policy is `CLASS` (not `RUNTIME`), while the annotations present in class files they are ignored by the runtime. It's not necessary to add your annotation pack to the classpath at all.

Comment: <<As annotations' retention policy is `CLASS` (not `RUNTIME`)>>

Why do you think the retention policy is `CLASS`?

Just in case, even `CLASS` requires to keep annotations on the class path: https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/issues/300#issuecomment-507305040

Comment: Re: Why do you think the retention policy is CLASS -- because that's what in the question. Re: Just in case, even CLASS requires to keep annotations on the class path -- 1) for compilation, not at runtime 2) for Scala